# Centering table and its catption as well as justifying caption which spans multiple lines

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I wonder how to center table and its catption as well as justifying caption which spans multiple lines. Below is MWE. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[format=plain,  justification=centering, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{justification=justified}
\caption{Logits Implied by Indicator Variables\\ in Model, $logit\left[P\left(Y=1\right)\right]=\alpha+\beta_{1}x+\beta_{2}z$}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule 
$x$ & $z$ & Logit\tabularnewline
\midrule
0 & 0 & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
1 & 0 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}$\tabularnewline
0 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
1 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{center}

\vspace{15cm}

\begin{table}
\caption{Logits Implied by Indicator Variables\\ in Model, $logit\left[P\left(Y=1\right)\right]=\alpha+\beta_{1}x+\beta_{2}z$}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule 
$x$ & $z$ & Logit\tabularnewline
\midrule
0 & 0 & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
1 & 0 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}$\tabularnewline
0 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
1 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using ``\\`` in the caption, if you want justification? What do you mean by “centering and justifying”?

Comment: Caption is too long and table is based on only three small columns.

Comment: I saw that. It's not at all clear what you're after. Perhaps setting a wider margin for the caption?

Comment: @MYaseen208 - Does it help if you drop that ``\\`` and set something like `\captionsetup{justification=justified, width=0.6\linewidth}`?  Or setting the caption beside the table?

Comment: @egreg I think he wants the caption centered, but justified (i.e. it doesn't exceed the table width).

Comment: Thanks @ArashEsbati for your helpful comment. Would you mind to change your comment to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the width of captions on a per float basis with the `width` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{justification=justified,width=0.6\linewidth}
  \caption{Logits Implied by Indicator Variables in Model,
    $logit\left[P\left(Y=1\right)\right]=\alpha+\beta_{1}x+\beta_{2}z$}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule 
    $x$ & $z$ & Logit\tabularnewline \midrule
    0 & 0 & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
    1 & 0 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}$\tabularnewline
    0 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
    1 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{position=top}
  \captionbox{Logits Implied by Indicator Variables in Model,
    $logit\left[P\left(Y=1\right)\right]=\alpha+\beta_{1}x+\beta_{2}z$}{%
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule 
      $x$ & $z$ & Logit\tabularnewline\midrule
      0 & 0 & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
      1 & 0 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}$\tabularnewline
      0 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
      1 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If the caption should have the same width as the table, you can use the `\captionbox` command also provided by `caption.sty`.  I would recommend the caption beside table.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

From your question and its comments I guess that you like to achieve something like this (assuming, that you haw two column text):

[image]

For center table you should use `\centering`. Use `\begin{center} ... >float> ..\end{center}` is wrong and gives error in compilation. For centering of caption, I guess that you actually look for option `justification=centerlast`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[format=plain,
            justification=centerlast, 
%            singlelinecheck=false
            ]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[hbt]
    \centering
\caption{Logits Implied by Indicator Variables in Model, $logit\left[P\left(Y=1\right)\right]=\alpha+\beta_{1}x+\beta_{2}z$
some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text
}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
$x$ & $z$ & Logit\tabularnewline
    \midrule
0 & 0 & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
1 & 0 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}$\tabularnewline
0 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
1 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Logits Implied by Indicator Variables}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
$x$ & $z$ & Logit\tabularnewline
    \midrule
0 & 0 & $\alpha$\tabularnewline
1 & 0 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}$\tabularnewline
0 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
1 & 1 & $\alpha+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```